# How to merge two arrays into one in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, controllers, array-merge

This is my config file which contains form attributes in CodeIgniter.

```
 $config['reg_attribute'] = array(

        'form'  => array(

                        'id' => 'reg-form',
                        'class' => 'form-horizontal', 
                        'role' => 'form'  
                        ),

        'name'  => array(
                        'id'=>'reg-name',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name'=>'name',
                        'placeholder' => 'Enter name',
                        'value'=>set_value('name')
                        ),      

        'gender'  => array(
                        'id'=>'reg-reg',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name'=>'gender',
                        'value'=>set_value('gender')
                        ),  

        'contact_no'  => array(
                        'id'=>'reg-reg',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name'=>'contact_no',
                        'placeholder' => 'Enter Phone number',
                        'value'=>set_value('contact_no')
                        ),                                      

        'email'=> array(

                        'id'=>'reg-email',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name'=>'email',
                        'placeholder' => 'Enter Email',
                        'value'=>set_value('email')
                        ),

        'password' =>array(

                        'id'=>'reg-password',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name'=>'password',
                        'placeholder'=>'Enter Password',
                        'value'=>set_value('password')

                        ),
        'confirm_password' =>array(

                        'id'=>'reg-password',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name'=>'confirm_password',
                        'placeholder'=>'Enter Confirm Password',
                        'value'=>set_value('confirm_password')

                        ),              

        'submit' =>array(

                       'id'          => 'btn-login',
                       'class'       => 'btn btn-success',
                       'name'        => 'submit',
                       'value'       => 'Register'

                      )
           );
```

Here I'm loading the form attributes from config and storing it into
an array `$data["reg_attrib"]`

```
$this->config->load('reg_rules');
$data["reg_attrib"] = $this->config->item("reg_attribute");
```

I have an another array which is  `$add_form`

```
 $add_form = array(
                'action' => base_url('admin/user/insert'),
                'title' => 'Add User',
            );
```

Now I want to merge both the array's into a single array 
and send it to view i.e to `$add_attributes`.

```
$this->admin_layout->view('admin/add_user',$add_attributes);
```

Comment: `$add_attributes = array_merge($data["reg_attrib"],$add_form);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply merge them with `array_merge()`. Try this -

```
$add_attributes = array_merge($data["reg_attrib"], $add_form);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `array_merge()` function like

```
$merged_arr = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```

in your case it will be same as @BOSE suggested:

```
$add_attributes = array_merge($data["reg_attrib"], $add_form);
```